# Convergence of series - alternating or root test

Tags: calculus

If we have the series:

$$\sum (-1)^n \frac{n^3}{3^n}$$

If theres a $(-1)^n$, that doesn't necessarily mean we would need to use the alternating series test to see if the series converges right?
So for example for this question, could we be able to use the root test and find out this series converges?

Comment: In addition to the ratio test used below, root test would work too.  It is actually a theorem that if a series converges by the ratio test, then it also converges by the root test.

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: The alternating series test works too. Since an exponential always grows faster than a polynomial, the limit of their ratio will go to 0

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n = (-1)^n\frac{n^3}{3^n} $. Then

$$ \left| \frac{ a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \frac{(n+1)^3}{3^{n+1}} \frac{3^n}{n^3} = \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)^3 \to \frac{1}{3} < 1$$

Hence, by the ratio test $\sum a_n $ converges absolutely $\implies $it converges

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ratio test to see that the series converges absolutely, and hence converges even with the $(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Using root test:
$$limsup\frac{|{n}^{3}|}{|{3}^{n}|}^{\frac{1}{n}}=lim\frac{{({n}^{\frac{1}{n}})}^{3}}{3}=\frac{1}{3}<1$$
So series diverges.